Upgrading multistage docker from yarn 1 to yarn modern
I have a Dockerfile written using old yarn

FROM node:20-alpine  AS dependencies
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn  install --production --frozen-lockfile && yarn cache clean


FROM node:20-alpine  AS builder
WORKDIR /app
RUN yarn global add typescript@5.5.4
COPY --from=dependencies /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .
RUN yarn build


FROM node:20-alpine  AS runner
WORKDIR /app
COPY entrypoint.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/build ./
COPY --from=builder /app/.env ./
COPY --from=dependencies /app/node_modules ./node_modules
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "entrypoint.js"]

Now, I want to rewrite this Dockerfile using Yarn 4, but I'm encountering a few issues:

No node_modules folder in Yarn 4 : Yarn 4 no longer generates a node_modules folder, so using COPY --from=dependencies /app/node_modules ./node_modules won’t work. If I want to use Yarn in every stage, it seems like the multi-stage setup becomes pointless. What’s the best approach here? also should I copy pnp* files or not ? I didnt find any proper document on this

No global add in Yarn 4 : In the builder stage, I currently use yarn global add typescript@5.5.4 But since Yarn 4 no longer supports global installs, how can I achieve a similar result for adding TypeScript?

Caching Yarn commands :
I’ve learned that you can cache the Yarn command using: --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.yarn YARN_CACHE_FOLDER=/root/.yarn yarn --immutable But if I clear the Docker cache folder, what impact will that have on my image ? will it stop working ?




No node_modules folder in Yarn 4 : Yarn 4 no longer generates a
node_modules folder, so using COPY --from=dependencies
/app/node_modules ./node_modules won’t work. If I want to use Yarn in
every stage, it seems like the multi-stage setup becomes pointless.
What’s the best approach here? also should I copy pnp* files or not ?
I didnt find any proper document on this

Since Yarn 4, we no longer need to copy node_modules, instead, we need to copy the .pnp.cjs, .pnp.loader.mjs, and .yarn folder to the next stage.
COPY --from=dependencies /app/.pnp.cjs ./
COPY --from=dependencies /app/.pnp.loader.mjs ./
COPY --from=dependencies /app/.yarn ./.yarn


No global add in Yarn 4 : In the builder stage, I currently use yarn global add typescript@5.5.4 But since Yarn 4 no longer supports global installs, how can I achieve a similar result for adding TypeScript?

We can use yarn dlx for this. For example, instead of RUN yarn build, we should use RUN yarn dlx -p typescript@5.5.4 tsc ( more info on official yarn documents ) also for some unknown reasons using package.json scripts with dlx is not working so I had to use tsc directly

Caching Yarn commands : I’ve learned that you can cache the Yarn
command using: --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.yarn
YARN_CACHE_FOLDER=/root/.yarn yarn --immutable But if I clear the
Docker cache folder, what impact will that have on my image ? will it
stop working ?

From my research, it seems that Yarn uses a cache folder. For Alpine with Yarn 4, the location is /root/.yarn/berry/cache. You can find the URL with yarn config get cacheFolder.
In a multi-stage build, you also need to copy this folder to avoid reinstalling Yarn modules:
COPY --from=dependencies /root/.yarn /root/.yarn

Additionally, it's better not to rely on Docker's cache, as Docker can remove it at any time, which might cause your program to stop working. (I haven’t tested this myself, so this is speculative. It would be very helpful if anyone with more insight could elaborate on this.)
Also to enable yarn 4 don't forget to add corepack enable to all your stages.
Mixing all these points, here is the new Dockerfile, which is working fine based on my testing:
FROM node:20-alpine AS dependencies
RUN corepack enable
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn --immutable

FROM node:20-alpine AS builder
RUN corepack enable
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=dependencies /app/.pnp.cjs ./
COPY --from=dependencies /app/.pnp.loader.mjs ./
COPY --from=dependencies /app/.yarn ./.yarn
COPY --from=dependencies /app/.yarn ./.yarn
COPY --from=dependencies /root/.yarn /root/.yarn
# when you use Copy . . dont forget to add .dockerignore with proper ignore items so that the host items doesnt replace your configs (like env or build files)
COPY . . 
RUN yarn dlx -p typescript@5.5.4 tsc


FROM node:20-alpine AS runner
RUN corepack enable
WORKDIR /app
COPY entrypoint.js ./
RUN apk add --no-cache mysql-client mariadb-connector-c
RUN mkdir backups
COPY --from=builder /app/build ./
COPY --from=builder /app/.env ./
COPY --from=dependencies /app/.pnp.cjs ./
COPY --from=dependencies /app/.pnp.loader.mjs ./
COPY --from=dependencies /app/.yarn ./.yarn
COPY --from=dependencies /root/.yarn /root/.yarn
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "entrypoint.js"]

